# ReferenceError: self is not defined in Angular SSR

Tags: angular, npm, server-side-rendering, serverless, angular-universal

**Recently i added Angular SSR to my existing project and when I'm trying to run it using `npm run dev:ssr`
i get the below mention Error.**

**I try to create new project and add SSR to it and it works fine.**

**But when i try to add SSR to existing project this error occurs**

```
D:\Projects\Angular\VajiraW\backend\dist\multikart-backend\server\main.js:199163
})(self, function() {
   ^

ReferenceError: self is not defined
    at Object.eeMe (D:\Projects\Angular\VajiraW\backend\dist\multikart-backend\server\main.js:199163:4)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\Projects\Angular\VajiraW\backend\dist\multikart-backend\server\main.js:20:30)
    at Module.YpNe (D:\Projects\Angular\VajiraW\backend\dist\multikart-backend\server\main.js:176155:66)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\Projects\Angular\VajiraW\backend\dist\multikart-backend\server\main.js:20:30)
    at Module.UZG+ (D:\Projects\Angular\VajiraW\backend\dist\multikart-backend\server\main.js:163034:78)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\Projects\Angular\VajiraW\backend\dist\multikart-backend\server\main.js:20:30)
    at Module.c9hY (D:\Projects\Angular\VajiraW\backend\dist\multikart-backend\server\main.js:188309:100)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\Projects\Angular\VajiraW\backend\dist\multikart-backend\server\main.js:20:30)
    at Module.IqRD (D:\Projects\Angular\VajiraW\backend\dist\multikart-backend\server\main.js:97334:82)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\Projects\Angular\VajiraW\backend\dist\multikart-backend\server\main.js:20:30)

A server error has occurred.
node exited with 1 code.
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:59833
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! multikart-backend@0.0.0 dev:ssr: `ng run multikart-backend:serve-ssr`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the multikart-backend@0.0.0 dev:ssr script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Danura\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-05T05_09_28_952Z-debug.log
```

**This is my Server.ts**

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { applyDomino } from '@ntegral/ngx-universal-window';
import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';

const BROWSER_DIR = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/multikart-backend/browser');
applyDomino(global, join(BROWSER_DIR, 'index.html'));

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/multikart-backend/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

***Can anyone help me to fix this. i have been stuck with this for Two days now***

Comment: Show the contents of server.ts?

Comment: @MikeOne I added it to my Question. Please Check

Comment: I can't see anything there that directly references 'self'. So check your imports and try to find out where self is declared. Also - check your node version. Make sure your stuff is compatible with it.

Comment: Tried Everything and nothing works s far. stuck on this for week now.

Comment: @ShaneBrewt Did you solve it?